# Hot key combo to submit simultaneous Tab plus Enter

Tags: autohotkey, keystrokes

I need to create a key combo, preferably <kbd>Right Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> that will actually submit a simultaneous press of 'tab plus enter'.  The hotkey combo can be any combo that can be done with the right hand, and obviously needs to be non-printing keys.

Would greatly appreciate some education here.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, here. Maybe you could tell us *why* you need this. In what context is this useful to you?

Comment: The context is that I use a site which requires simultaneous tab+enter to perform a function often.  That is a twwo-handed operation.  I would like to have a key combo that can be touched with right hand fingers only, to simplify the operation.

Comment: what language/framework?

Comment: Wow.  Don't even know how to answer that or what a framework is.  Just trying to use Autohotkey on a Windows 7 laptop to creat the macro described in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on Windows, you can use this [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script to map <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to <kbd>Tab</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
+ENTER::Send,{TAB DOWN}{ENTER}{TAB UP}
```

If you want to limit this mapping to when the browser window is open to a specific page, you can usually do it by identifying a unique window title. For example, if you use Chrome and wanted this mapping to work only when you are on StackOverflow.com, you could use this script:

```
SetTitleMatchMode,2

#IfWinActive Stack Overflow - Google Chrome
    +ENTER::Send,{TAB DOWN}{ENTER}{TAB UP}
```

The `SetTitleMatchMode,2` value means that we allow partial matching of window titles instead of requiring a full, exact match.

The `#IfWinActive` specifies that the mappings below should only be in effect when a window with the specified [partial] title is active.

The mapping is `+ENTER` (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>) on the left of `::` and the action to execute on the right is to `Send` keystrokes: hold <kbd>Tab</kbd> down, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, release <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Comment: OK!  I think that is getting close.  Will go try to implement that. As for to specific page no.  I'd like it to work only when Chrome is open, but full page url will be different on occasions when macro needs to be active. Is that title text treated as EXACT or as "contains?"  If contains is the answer, I can use it.

Comment: Oops...now see that the ,2 makes it a partial match (= contains).           Is there any way to make it activate only using the RIGHT shft key?

Comment: @user2321353 Yes! Replace `+ENTER` with `RShift & Enter`

Comment: Well, this is interesting.  The Chrome browser does not seem to have a Window title on it.

Comment: @user2321353 Hold Alt and press Tab until it is highlighted and you will see the title. It is also in the task bar and Task Manager.

Comment: Good info!  Thanks indeed.  

So, it would be 
"RShift & Enter::Send,{TAB DOWN}{ENTER}{TAB UP}" ?  .....How do you make paragraphs when typing these comments!!? ..........As for "Hold Alt and press Tab until it is highlighted and you will see the title", when I do that and the selection lands on the Chrome icon, there is NO TEXT in the field that shows all the other one's titles.  The Chrome window HAS NO TITLE!

Comment: @user2321353 That is odd; I see window title text, but I am using Windows 8 so it could be some difference there.

Comment: Just to report for completeness, this DOES WORK.  Thanks very much.